Efficiently storing data that is partially columnar into a DuckDB database in a purely columnar form
I have some partially columnar data like this:
"hello", "2024 JAN", "2024 FEB"
"a", 0, 1

If it were purely columnar, it would look like:
"hello", "year", "month", "value"
"a", 2024, "JAN", 0
"a", 2024, "FEB", 1

Suppose the data is in the form of a numpy array, like this:
import numpy as np

data = np.array([["hello", "2024 JAN", "2024 FEB"], ["a", "0", "1"]], dtype="<U")
data

array([['hello', '2024 JAN', '2024 FEB'],
       ['a', '0', '1']], dtype='<U8')

Imagine also that I created a table:
import duckdb as ddb

conn = ddb.connect("hello.db")
conn.execute("CREATE TABLE columnar (hello VARCHAR, year UINTEGER, month VARCHAR, value VARCHAR);")

How could I go about efficiently inserting data into the DuckDB table columnar?
The naive/easy way would be to brute-force transform the data into a columnar format in-memory, in Python, before inserting it into the DuckDB table.
Here I mean specifically:
import re

data_header = data[0]
data_proper = data[1:]

date_pattern = re.compile(r"(?P<year>[\d]+) (?P<month>JAN|FEB)")
common_labels: list[str] = []
known_years: set[int] = set()
known_months: set[str] = set()
header_to_date: Dict[str, tuple[int, str]] = dict()
for header in data_header:
    if matches := date_pattern.match(header):
        year, month = int(matches["year"]), str(matches["month"])
        known_years.add(year)
        known_months.add(month)
        header_to_date[header] = (year, month)
    else:
        common_labels.append(header)

# hello, year, month, value
new_rows_per_old_row = len(known_years) * len(known_months)
new_headers = ["year", "month", "value"]
purely_columnar = np.empty(
    (
        1 + data_proper.shape[0] * new_rows_per_old_row,
        len(common_labels) + len(new_headers),
    ),
    dtype=np.object_,
)
purely_columnar[0] = common_labels + ["year", "month", "value"]
for rx, row in enumerate(data_proper):
    common_data = []
    ym_data = []
    for header, element in zip(data_header, row):
        if header in common_labels:
            common_data.append(element)
        else:
            year, month = header_to_date[header]
            ym_data.append([year, month, element])

    for yx, year_month_value in enumerate(ym_data):
        purely_columnar[
            1 + rx * new_rows_per_old_row + yx, : len(common_labels)
        ] = common_data
        purely_columnar[
            1 + rx * new_rows_per_old_row + yx, len(common_labels) :
        ] = year_month_value

print(f"{purely_columnar=}")

purely_columnar=
array([[np.str_('hello'), 'year', 'month', 'value'],
       [np.str_('a'), 2024, 'JAN', np.str_('0')],
       [np.str_('a'), 2024, 'FEB', np.str_('1')]], dtype=object)

Now it is easy enough to store this data in DuckDB:
purely_columnar_data = np.transpose(purely_columnar[1:])
conn.execute(
    """INSERT INTO columnar
    SELECT * FROM purely_columnar_data
  """
)
conn.sql("SELECT * FROM columnar")

┌─────────┬────────┬─────────┬─────────┐
│  hello  │  year  │  month  │  value  │
│ varchar │ uint32 │ varchar │ varchar │
├─────────┼────────┼─────────┼─────────┤
│ a       │   2024 │ JAN     │ 0       │
│ a       │   2024 │ FEB     │ 1       │
└─────────┴────────┴─────────┴─────────┘

But is there any other way in which I can insert the data into a DuckDB in a purely columnar form, apart from brute-forcing the data into a purely columnar form first?
Note: I have tagged this question with postgresql because DuckDB's SQL dialect closely follows that of PostgreSQL.

What is the easy way you are referring to? Do you mean something like first = data[: :1].T; rest = data[:, :1]; duckdb.sql("from first positional join rest") - (ignoring the splitting of the date momentarily)

It might help to post Python/pandas code that does the transformation you're looking for. This may help identify the SQL equivalent.

@jqurious I'm new to SQL, so I do not quite understand your "easy way". I updated the question with what I think might be the "easy way" (brute-forcing the data in Python into a "purely columnar form").

@IanGow I updated the question with this! I am not using pandas; just Python and numpy.

If you are actually starting with raw text and using regex to extract specific parts - this may be an "XY problem". You could just use read_text() to load the data into DuckDB and use its own regex functions instead of doing it in Python.

@bzm3r Cool. Seems you got an answer.

Note: I added another row ("b",1,0) to make the data a bit more substantive so that it's easier to see what's happening.
Essentially what you have is a "pivoted" dataset:
D SELECT * FROM 'pivoted-data.csv';
┌─────────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│  hello  │ 2024 JAN │ 2024 FEB │
│ varchar │  int64   │  int64   │
├─────────┼──────────┼──────────┤
│ a       │        0 │        1 │
│ b       │        1 │        0 │
└─────────┴──────────┴──────────┘

So UNPIVOT it:
D SELECT hello, string_split(month, ' ')[1]::INTEGER AS year, string_split(month, ' ')[2] AS month, value
  FROM (UNPIVOT 'pivoted-data.csv' ON '2024 JAN', '2024 FEB' INTO NAME month VALUE value);
┌─────────┬───────┬─────────┬───────┐
│  hello  │ year  │  month  │ value │
│ varchar │ int32 │ varchar │ int64 │
├─────────┼───────┼─────────┼───────┤
│ a       │  2024 │ JAN     │     0 │
│ a       │  2024 │ FEB     │     1 │
│ b       │  2024 │ JAN     │     1 │
│ b       │  2024 │ FEB     │     0 │
└─────────┴───────┴─────────┴───────┘

Following which you could use one of the string functions to parse the month further.
EDIT: I had a crack at splitting the string, it's not the most efficient, but I figured the query optimiser probably sees the code duplication, and optimises it.
EDIT2: Okay, EXPLAIN confirms that the duplication is optimised away:
┌─────────────────────────────┐
│┌───────────────────────────┐│
││       Physical Plan       ││
│└───────────────────────────┘│
└─────────────────────────────┘
┌───────────────────────────┐
│         PROJECTION        │
│   ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─   │
│           hello           │
│            year           │
│           month           │
│           value           │
└─────────────┬─────────────┘
┌─────────────┴─────────────┐
│         PROJECTION        │
│   ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─   │
│           hello           │
│  string_split(month, ' ') │
│           value           │
└─────────────┬─────────────┘
┌─────────────┴─────────────┐
│         PROJECTION        │
│   ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─   │
│             #0            │
│             #3            │
│             #4            │
└─────────────┬─────────────┘
┌─────────────┴─────────────┐
│           FILTER          │
│   ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─   │
│    (value IS NOT NULL)    │
│   ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─   │
│           EC: 1           │
└─────────────┬─────────────┘
┌─────────────┴─────────────┐
│           UNNEST          │
└─────────────┬─────────────┘
┌─────────────┴─────────────┐
│       READ_CSV_AUTO       │
│   ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─   │
│           hello           │
│          2024 JAN         │
│          2024 FEB         │
│   ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─   │
│           EC: 3           │
└───────────────────────────┘


How does the EXPLAIN confirm that the code duplication is gone?

@bzm3r Look at the 2nd projection from the top, only one string_split, and in the top one it is only accessing the elements (by the names that were given).

A slight variant on the answer from @suvayu:
SELECT hello, CAST(strptime(month, '%Y %b') AS DATE) AS month, value
FROM (
  UNPIVOT 'pivoted-data.csv'
  ON COLUMNS(* EXCLUDE (hello)) 
  INTO NAME month VALUE value);

The two differences are:

Use of strptime() to parse the date.
Use of a COLUMNS expression to make the query a little more dynamic (I assume the real data set has more dates in it).


Ah nice! The EXCLUDE keyword is DuckDB specific I think, really handy, reduces typing. Thanks for reminding me :)
